# SQL Server distinct rows count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say there is the following table in SQL Server :

```
 ID Column1 Column2 Column3
  1    1       2       10
  1    1       2       20
  2    1       2       30
  2    1       2       40
  3    3       4       50
  3    3       4       60
  3    3       4       70
```

I need to select the SUM on Column3 grouped by Column1, Column2 and select the count of rows with DISTINCT "ID". Consider the query :

```
  SELECT SUM(Column3) AS Column3
         COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY Column1,
           Column2
```

The result will be :

```
  Column3 Count
    100     4
    110     3
```

I expect to get :

```
  Column3 Count
    100     2
    110     1
```

So the count here will be by DISTINCT "ID" values. 
In the first row 2 means there are two different ID values (1 and 2) with the same Column1, Column2
In the second row 1 means there is just one distinct value (that is 3) with the same Column1, Column2.

Can you please advice me the correct way to get the expected result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx

```
 SELECT SUM(Column3) AS Column3
         COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Count
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY Column1,
           Column2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm understanding you right, but does this work?:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT ID, column1, column2, SUM(column3) AS column3sum FROM table GROUP BY id, column1, column2)

SELECT SUM(column3sum), COUNT(ID)
FROM cte
GROUP BY column1, column2
```